# How to fix "TypeError: results.map is not a function", in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, array.prototype.map

```
function Results(props) {
  var results = props.results;
  return (
    <>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Book Name</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>S.no</th>
            <th>Series Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
            <th>Kindle/Real</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {results.map(result => {
            return (
              <tr key={result.name}>
                <td>{result.name}</td>
                <td>{result.author}</td>
                <td>{result.sno}</td>
                <td>{result.series}</td>
                <td>{result.type}</td>
                <td>{result.genre}</td>
                <td>{result.kindeReal}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  );
}
```

When I try to render the above com component, I get the error:

> TypeError: results.map is not a function

The results variable is an array of objects, something like:

```
[{"type":1},{"type":0},{"type":2}]
```

However, when I use the .map function, it returns the error! It is clearly an array, so why can't I use it?

This is the output of console.log(results).

```
[{"Book_Name":"Time Riders","Author":"Alex Scarrow","S_no":1,"Series_Name":"Time Riders","Fiction_Non_fiction_Companion_Prequel":"Fiction","Genre":"Sci-fi/Mystery/Thriller","Kindle_Real":"Real"},{"Book_Name":"Day of the Predator ","Author":"Alex Scarrow","S_no":2,"Series_Name":"Time Riders","Fiction_Non_fiction_Companion_Prequel":"Fiction","Genre":"Sci-fi/Mystery/Thriller","Kindle_Real":"Real"},{"Book_Name":"The Doomsday Code","Author":"Alex Scarrow","S_no":3,"Series_Name":"Time Riders","Fiction_Non_fiction_Companion_Prequel":"Fiction","Genre":"Sci-fi/Mystery/Thriller","Kindle_Real":"Real"},{"Book_Name":"The Eternal War","Author":"Alex Scarrow","S_no":4,"Series_Name":"Time Riders","Fiction_Non_fiction_Companion_Prequel":"Fiction","Genre":"Sci-fi/Mystery/Thriller","Kindle_Real":"Real"},{"Book_Name":"Gates of Rome","Author":"Alex Scarrow","S_no":5,"Series_Name":"Time Riders","Fiction_Non_fiction_Companion_Prequel":"Fiction","Genre":"Sci-fi/Mystery/Thriller","Kindle_Real":"Real"},{"Book_Name":"City of Shadows","Author":"Alex Scarrow","S_no":6,"Series_Name":"Time Riders","Fiction_Non_fiction_Companion_Prequel":"Fiction","Genre":"Sci-fi/Mystery/Thriller","Kindle_Real":"Real"},{"Book_Name":"The Pirate Kings","Author":"Alex Scarrow","S_no":7,"Series_Name":"Time Riders","Fiction_Non_fiction_Companion_Prequel":"Fiction","Genre":"Sci-fi/Mystery/Thriller","Kindle_Real":"Real"},{"Book_Name":"The Mayan Prophecy","Author":"Alex Scarrow","S_no":8,"Series_Name":"Time Riders","Fiction_Non_fiction_Companion_Prequel":"Fiction","Genre":"Sci-fi/Mystery/Thriller","Kindle_Real":"Real"},{"Book_Name":"The Infinity Cage","Author":"Alex Scarrow","S_no":9,"Series_Name":"Time Riders","Fiction_Non_fiction_Companion_Prequel":"Fiction","Genre":"Sci-fi/Mystery/Thriller","Kindle_Real":"Real"}]
```

It looks like an array to me. Why is it not an array then?

This is the parent component.

```
import React from "react";
import Results from "./results";

function ResultsRenderer(props) {
  if (props.status === true) {
    return <Results results={props.results} />;
  } else {
    return <>{"No"}</>;
  }
}

export default ResultsRenderer;
```

This is the parent component of ResultsRenderer.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Form from "./searcherFormDumb";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import ResultsRenderer from "./resultsRenderer";

function Searcher() {
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState(["Empty", false]);
  const [book, setBook] = useState({
    name: "",
    author: "",
    sno: null,
    series: "",
    type: "",
    genre: "",
    kindleReal: ""
  });
  const defaultState = {
    name: "",
    author: "",
    sno: null,
    series: "",
    type: "",
    genre: "",
    kindleReal: ""
  };

  function handleChange(event) {
    const updatedBook = { ...book, [event.target.name]: event.target.value };
    setBook(updatedBook);
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var changed = {};
    function populateChanged(now, old, title, temp) {
      if (now !== old) {
        temp[title] = now;
        return temp;
      } else {
        return temp;
      }
    }
    changed = populateChanged(
      book.name,
      defaultState.name,
      "Book_Name",
      changed
    );
    changed = populateChanged(
      book.author,
      defaultState.author,
      "Author",
      changed
    );
    changed = populateChanged(book.sno, defaultState.sno, "S_no", changed);
    changed = populateChanged(
      book.series,
      defaultState.series,
      "Series_Name",
      changed
    );
    changed = populateChanged(
      book.type,
      defaultState.type,
      "Fiction_Non_fiction_Companion_Prequel",
      changed
    );
    changed = populateChanged(book.genre, defaultState.genre, "Genre", changed);
    changed = populateChanged(
      book.kindleReal,
      defaultState.kindleReal,
      "Kindle_Real",
      changed
    );
    var temp_string = "";
    var key = "";
    var value = "";
    var temp_string_list = [];
    //debugger;
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(changed).length; i++) {
      //debugger;
      key = Object.keys(changed)[i];
      value = changed[key];
      if (i !== Object.keys(changed).length - 1) {
        temp_string = `${key} = "${value}" AND `;
      } else if (i === Object.keys(changed).length - 1) {
        temp_string = `${key} = "${value}"`;
      }
      temp_string_list.push(temp_string);
      //debugger;
      temp_string = "";
      key = "";
      value = "";
    }

    var sql_t = temp_string_list.join("");
    var sql_tt = "SELECT * FROM books_catalouge WHERE ";
    var sql = sql_tt + sql_t;
    toast.success(sql);

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var jsql = JSON.stringify(sql);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      //debugger;
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        setAnswer([this.responseText, true]);
        console.log(`${answer}`);
      }
    };
    request.open(
      "GET",
      "http://localhost:3001/retrieve_books" + "?msg=" + jsql,
      true
    );
    request.send(jsql);
    console.log("This is the END");
    console.log(`${answer}`);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Form book={book} onChange={handleChange} onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
      <br />
      <ResultsRenderer status={answer[1]} results={answer[0]} />
    </>
  );
}

export default Searcher;
```

Let me know if you need the NodeJS as well. I am using SQL to get the data, which is why I need the NodeJS. Sorry if my code is a little weird.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sounds like the first time it loads there is no data.... `console.log("I am ", results);` and see what it is

Comment: You may want to verify that `props.results` contains the array you think it does. Maybe use a `console.log` to double check.

Comment: Where `results` passed into this function ?

Comment: @jdn... look at the code

Comment: Please console.log(props.results) in the first line, and add the result to the question.

Comment: You're probably using `<Results results={this.state.x} />` in the parent component. All you need to do to fix this is to make sure that `this.state.x` is *always* an Array, i.e. starts out as `[]`.

Comment: Try logging `typeof results`, my suspicion is that it's a string instead of an array

Comment: @Ferrybig Yeah, it was a string. Thanks for the debugging suggestion. I consoled logged it, and it looked like an array, so I left it at that. Will try `typeof` if I ever face a similar problem again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Function `map()` can be used only on **array**. In this situation it looks like `props.results` is not array or has not been set yet (this can happen if you are fetching data with Axios or something like that).

I would recommend you to place something like this at the start of function:

```
if (!props.results) return 'no data';
if (!Array.isArray(props.results)) return 'results are not array'
```

---

#### after clarification

You get response on your `onreadystatechange` request which usualy comes in JSON or XML. I think your answer is stringified json. Try to use `JSON.parse(response)` in case of JSON or `(new DOMParser()).parseFromString(response,"text/xml")` in case of XML.

In your component it may look like this

```
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
   (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
      && setAnswer([JSON.parse(this.responseText), true]);
};
```

Comment: It returns, 'results are not array'.

Comment: So... your results are not array and function `map` is only for arrays. Can you dump it with `console.log()` and post what has been printed?

Comment: Done. It looks like an array, for some reason.

Comment: Are you sure that error is being thrown in this Component/code? I've [tested your variable dumps](https://jsfiddle.net/c1hxyb2L/) and yes, they are array (used same function as I've mentioned in my answer so if the value is same, it won't says it is not array). Another possible problem could be if you are using some `async` or `Promise` function (again, it can be Axios or Fetch too). Can you show me the parent component where is this one being rendered from?

Comment: Sure. Give me a sec

Comment: Done. I've added the parent components.

Comment: I've found one possibility that could cause this. Check my updated answer. JSON object in console.log looks very similar to javascript object.

Comment: It works! Thanks. Sorry for the late acknowledgment. I didn't get the chance to continue on my app till now. It was a string (I checked with typeof), but your solution fixed it! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing similar behavior when deserializing a simple .json file:

```
const stringifiedData = fs.readFileSync(animalsPath);
const animalData = JSON.parse(stringifiedData);
const animals = animalData.map(animal => {
    return new Animal(animal)
})
```

Oddly, the example I'm following is doing a string dot notation that seems to satisfy V8 that the object is an array, even though it's output in console.out does not change. The following does work but I don't know why. Any ideas?

```
const stringifiedData = fs.readFileSync(animalsPath);
const animalData = JSON.parse(stringifiedData).animals;
const animals = animalData.map(animal => {
    return new Animal(animal)
})
```

Comment: Helped me, thank you.

Lost about an hour as I assumed the initial type would not matter (as its replaced with an array full on content later).

I had this:
const [newReply, setNewReply] = useState("");

Which I changed to this:
const [newReply, setNewReply] = useState([]);

and bingo.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same error while accessing data element of an array. here is what I did:

```
{standardObj ? (
    {standardObj.map((obj: any) => {
      return (
        <Grid item>
          <FormControlLabel
            className={styles.CheckboxLabel}
            key={obj.Code}
            control={
              <Checkbox
                onChange={handleCheckElement}
                name={obj.FullName}
                value={obj.Code}
              />
            }
            label={obj.FullName}
          />
        </Grid>
      );
    })}
) : null }
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and appars that for the useState Hook is very important the type of data of the inital value, I had as initial value a 0 int and cos that react didn't recognize the update as array.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to React and found out that if a variable is empty / undefined and used with "map" function, the React throws that exception. My solution was to check a variable for "undefined" and length > 0.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this problem is because of wrong syntax.

where there is

```
 results.map(result => {
 ........................
 }
```

just do

```
results.map(result => (
 ........................
 )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).