# react javascript test fails when I import props

Tags: javascript, testing, create-react-app, react-testing-library

here is my component:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
const Newbar = (props) => {
  const listitems = props.links.map((link) => {
    return (
      <li key={link.id}>
        <Link to={link.id}>{link.name}</Link>
      </li>
    );
  });
  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>{listitems}</ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Newbar;
```

This test passes

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Newbar from "./Newbar";
const signinlink = { id: "/", name: "Sign in" };
const aboutlink = { id: "about", name: "About" };
const links = [signinlink, aboutlink];
test("shows initial tabs", async () => {
  render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      
      <Newbar links={links}></Newbar>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
  const signinlink = screen.getByText("Sign in");
  const aboutlink = screen.getByText("About");
  expect(signinlink).toBeVisible();
  expect(aboutlink).toBeVisible();
});
```

but when I import the mock data the test fails with error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Newbar from "./Newbar";

import { signinlink, aboutlink } from "../../mocks/mockdata";

const links = [signinlink, aboutlink];
test("shows initial tabs", async () => {
  render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      
      <Newbar links={links}></Newbar>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
  const signinlink = screen.getByText("Sign in");
  const aboutlink = screen.getByText("About");
  expect(signinlink).toBeVisible();
  expect(aboutlink).toBeVisible();
});
```

Comment: async doesn't matter, test fails with or without

Comment: How does your mockdata look like?

Comment: the working test is just a copy of the mock data.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference: can you port your code over to a [codesandbox running React](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)? That'll create an [mcve] that is easy to troubleshoot.

Comment: I've never known how; i'll try

Comment: in the end after bug fixing, I just had to make sure i declared links as an array with [] instead of as an object with {}.  This question ends up being a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58343639/how-to-fix-typeerror-results-map-is-not-a-function-in-react